# fopen() with relative path

Tags: c++, visual-c++, file-io

I am have a trouble in using fopen() with relative path. I wanted to use fopen like this:

```
fopen("\\Saurabh\\pqrs.txt");
```

i am getting filePointer as null.

The situation arose because I am trying to create a setup or deployment project which has to read files. The file paths chosen by default after user executes setup are C:\Program Files\Setup..
(where exe is dumped). So I dumped the files in the same folder and gave path(fixed path or hardcoded) to those files in the program.

If the user selects some other path for installation, the program fails.

Is there any way I can fix this?

Answer (score 7):

Two problems:

1. You need to escape the backslash character. Write `\\`.
2. You need to use a relative path. By starting a path with `\\` you mean *start from the root directory*.

Putting these together, I think you should write:

```
fopen("Saurabh\\pqrs.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you double up the `\` characters. The string you're passing in should be `"Saurabh\\pqrs.txt"`. Note that beginning a path with `\\` means that it's not relative. (Well, actually it's relative to your current drive, but I doubt that's what you're looking for.)

Comment: I think for additional clarity it might be worth putting in a `.` in the directory path so that its 100% clear that you're starting with the current directory.  (In this case it would be `fopen(".\\Saurabh\\pqrs.txt")`)  On some systems, leading with a slash has implications.

Comment: `"C:\\Saurabh\\pqrs.txt"` is an absolute path; the OP says he wants to use a relative path.